# jQuery show content when clicked hide initially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a simple jQuery function to show / change a divs content depending on which link is clicked..

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.showSingle').on('click', function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
    jQuery('#div' + jQuery(this).data('target')).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.col-md-4{width:200px;background:red;clear:both;margin-bottom:10px;}
.p_content{clear:both;margin-top:300px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="p_link">
    <a class="showSingle" data-target="1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam iaculis orci id nulla aliquet fermentum. Suspendisse ultrices nulla id magna cursus blandit.
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 p_link">
  <a class="showSingle" data-target="2">
    Sed feugiat fringilla lacus, quis aliquam turpis cursus eu. In dignissim ultrices tellus in convallis. Sed euismod tellus vel lorem
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 p_link">
  <a class="showSingle" data-target="3">
    suscipit dignissim. Mauris ut velit sit amet enim sollicitudin molestie nec quis mauris
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="p_link">
    <a class="showSingle" data-target="4">
      ique sodales mi mi quis leo. Aliquam at eros vitae sem accumsan maximus. In non sapien faucibus, accumsan nisl eget, convallis 
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 p_link">
  <a class="showSingle" data-target="5">
    vitae, fermentum efficitur nisi. Vestibulum id tortor lacus. Phasellus convallis consequat rhoncus. Fusce sed facilisis risus.
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 p_link">
  <a class="showSingle" data-target="6">
    fringilla tempor odio. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce at porta orci. Nulla tempus convallis
  </a>
</div>
<div class="container p_content">
  <div id="div1" class="targetDiv">
    posuere dapibus. In blandit, tortor quis laoreet lobortis, sem est auctor eros, ut vulputate augue felis nec massa. Pellentesque sagittis mi ac leo dignissim, sed semper augue hendrerit. Quisque scelerisque ante quis ullamcorper placerat. Cras in porta turpis. Proin turpis mi, posuere vehicula mi vitae, fermentum efficitur nisi. Vestibulum id tortor lacus. Phasellus convallis consequat rhoncus. Fusce sed facilisis risus. Suspendisse vel mi auctor, pulvinar nibh auctor, consequat massa. Phasellus vel laoreet sem, sit am
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="targetDiv">
    idunt ante, eget pulvinar magna malesuada id. Morbi posuere libero sed ante tempor faucibus. Fusce non nulla nunc. Vestibulum lacinia leo arcu, ut efficitur nibh sodales sit amet. Maecenas non efficitur lectus, sit amet cursus sem. In nibh metus, sagittis eget ex id, fringilla tempor odio. Interdum et 
  </div>
  <div id="div3" class="targetDiv">
    erisque erat vel vehicula. In varius at massa id molestie. Donec nec nisi vel justo auctor laoreet. Ut commodo velit vitae magna faucibus elementum. Cras ultrices auctor risus, scelerisque aliquet nisi tincidunt id. Integer quis dapibus nibh. Praesent mauris eros, vestibulum at felis a, luctus laoreet tellus.
  </div>
  <div id="div4" class="targetDiv">
    e vehicula mi vitae, fermentum efficitur nisi. Vestibulum id tortor lacus. Phasellus convallis consequat rhoncus. Fusce sed facilisis risus. Suspendisse vel mi auctor, pulvinar nibh auctor, consequat massa. Phasellus vel laoreet sem, sit amet sodales urna
  </div>
  <div id="div5" class="targetDiv">
    gnissim ultrices tellus in convallis. Sed euismod tellus vel lorem suscipit dignissim. Mauris ut velit sit amet enim sollicitudin molestie nec quis mauris. Aenean quis maximus ex. Maecenas congue tellus ac nunc sodales pellentesque.
  </div>
  <div id="div6" class="targetDiv">
    Vestibulum lacinia leo arcu, ut efficitur nibh sodales sit amet. Maecenas non efficitur lectus, sit amet cursus sem. In nibh metus, sagittis eget ex id, fringilla tempor odio. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce at porta orci. Nulla tempus convallis nisi id cursus. Nunc ac turpis sem. In pellentesque rhoncus suscipit.
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/7939/

It all works correctly apart from two things:

1. When it first loads it displays all of the content until one of the options is clicked.
2. I would like to make it so that when one of the links is clicked the page jumps down to where the content it.

Could anybody point me in the right direction for achieving these two things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You just need to hide those elements using `display:none;` in the **css**.
2. My solution is to add a [`hash`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) to the URL and let the browser take care about the scrolling.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.showSingle').on('click', function () {
    jQuery(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    jQuery('.targetDiv').hide();
    var selector = '#div' + jQuery(this).data('target');
    jQuery(selector).show();
    location.hash = selector;
  });
});
```

```css
.col-md-4{width:200px;background:red;clear:both;margin-bottom:10px;}
.p_content{clear:both;margin-top:300px;}

/* add this */
.targetDiv {
  display:none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="p_link">
    <a class="showSingle" data-target="1">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam iaculis orci id nulla aliquet fermentum. Suspendisse ultrices nulla id magna cursus blandit.
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 p_link">
  <a class="showSingle" data-target="2">
    Sed feugiat fringilla lacus, quis aliquam turpis cursus eu. In dignissim ultrices tellus in convallis. Sed euismod tellus vel lorem
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 p_link">
  <a class="showSingle" data-target="3">
    suscipit dignissim. Mauris ut velit sit amet enim sollicitudin molestie nec quis mauris
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="p_link">
    <a class="showSingle" data-target="4">
      ique sodales mi mi quis leo. Aliquam at eros vitae sem accumsan maximus. In non sapien faucibus, accumsan nisl eget, convallis 
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 p_link">
  <a class="showSingle" data-target="5">
    vitae, fermentum efficitur nisi. Vestibulum id tortor lacus. Phasellus convallis consequat rhoncus. Fusce sed facilisis risus.
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 p_link">
  <a class="showSingle" data-target="6">
    fringilla tempor odio. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce at porta orci. Nulla tempus convallis
  </a>
</div>
<div class="container p_content">
  <div id="div1" class="targetDiv">
    posuere dapibus. In blandit, tortor quis laoreet lobortis, sem est auctor eros, ut vulputate augue felis nec massa. Pellentesque sagittis mi ac leo dignissim, sed semper augue hendrerit. Quisque scelerisque ante quis ullamcorper placerat. Cras in porta turpis. Proin turpis mi, posuere vehicula mi vitae, fermentum efficitur nisi. Vestibulum id tortor lacus. Phasellus convallis consequat rhoncus. Fusce sed facilisis risus. Suspendisse vel mi auctor, pulvinar nibh auctor, consequat massa. Phasellus vel laoreet sem, sit am
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="targetDiv">
    idunt ante, eget pulvinar magna malesuada id. Morbi posuere libero sed ante tempor faucibus. Fusce non nulla nunc. Vestibulum lacinia leo arcu, ut efficitur nibh sodales sit amet. Maecenas non efficitur lectus, sit amet cursus sem. In nibh metus, sagittis eget ex id, fringilla tempor odio. Interdum et 
  </div>
  <div id="div3" class="targetDiv">
    erisque erat vel vehicula. In varius at massa id molestie. Donec nec nisi vel justo auctor laoreet. Ut commodo velit vitae magna faucibus elementum. Cras ultrices auctor risus, scelerisque aliquet nisi tincidunt id. Integer quis dapibus nibh. Praesent mauris eros, vestibulum at felis a, luctus laoreet tellus.
  </div>
  <div id="div4" class="targetDiv">
    e vehicula mi vitae, fermentum efficitur nisi. Vestibulum id tortor lacus. Phasellus convallis consequat rhoncus. Fusce sed facilisis risus. Suspendisse vel mi auctor, pulvinar nibh auctor, consequat massa. Phasellus vel laoreet sem, sit amet sodales urna
  </div>
  <div id="div5" class="targetDiv">
    gnissim ultrices tellus in convallis. Sed euismod tellus vel lorem suscipit dignissim. Mauris ut velit sit amet enim sollicitudin molestie nec quis mauris. Aenean quis maximus ex. Maecenas congue tellus ac nunc sodales pellentesque.
  </div>
  <div id="div6" class="targetDiv">
    Vestibulum lacinia leo arcu, ut efficitur nibh sodales sit amet. Maecenas non efficitur lectus, sit amet cursus sem. In nibh metus, sagittis eget ex id, fringilla tempor odio. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce at porta orci. Nulla tempus convallis nisi id cursus. Nunc ac turpis sem. In pellentesque rhoncus suscipit.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just hide all the elements by class name using jquery on page load, or you can just use css 
    display:none;